# Google geocode API server key is denied

Tags: google-geocoding-api

The Google geocoding API used to work fine for me but I tried it again today and I keep getting

```
{
   "error_message" : "The provided API key is invalid.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

When I get the URL `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=New%20York&sensor=false&key=MY_KEY`. I've generated this (server) key just a few minutes ago so I see no particular reason why it would be invalid. Does anyone have any experience with something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2013-02-25:** API keys are [now supported with the Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#api_key), so this API call should now succeed, once the Geocoding API service is turned on, in the Google Developers Console.
Previously, it was required to remove the API key.